# forwarding rdp traffic using netsh

Tags: windows, networking, portforwarding, netsh

I'm trying to set up port forwarding on windows machine. I have the following setup:

1. Machine **P** with ip address *192.168.0.120* that is reachable from my network
2. Machine **D** with ip address *192.168.120.6* that is reachable from machine **D** network only.

I need to access machine **D**. Now I'm using rdp to **P**, and then launch rdp to **D**. That's not convenient. What I wanted to do, is forward rdp from **D** to my local machine over **P**.

```
netsh.exe interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=33891 connectport=3389 connectaddress=192.168.120.6
```

But when I try to connect using rdp to 192.168.0.120:33891 it fails. Telnet also can't open port 33891. So, port forwarding doesn't work.

I'll appreciate any suggestions, Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this tool [Port Redirection with Windows](http://codewut.de/Port-Redirection-with-Windows)

Comment: +1 This works, but isn't a direct answer. I'm really curious why it doesn't work via a `netsh v4tov4` redirection

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a firewall exception on machine P for port 33891?

Comment: I would echo @jeatsy's comment and say that it was most likely a firewall issue. Windows probably prompted with that rinetd application.